# ContainerRequestFilter dont work in a external package

Tags: java

I built a package to give a authentication handler. That engine will be triggered when a method/class as annotated with `@Secured` so the `ContainerRequestFilter` will be triggered.

But I'm using this library in another package and when I annoted a method with the `@Secured` the ContainerRequestFilter` engine is not triggered. So I need help with that.

I tried to import manually with `@Inject` and `@EJB` but when I deployed that application in weblogic container I got some errors about dependency.

AuthenticatePackage -

The interceptor:

```
import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.Priorities;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Secured
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION)
public class SecurityInterceptor implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;
    @Inject private JWTService jwtService;

    public static final String AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME = "Bearer";

....
```

The Annotation

```
import javax.ws.rs.NameBinding;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@NameBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface Secured {
    String[] roles() default {};
}
```

Package when I use that engine

```
  @GET
    @Path("/getSignedUser")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Secured
    public Response getSignedUser(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String token)  {
    UserSchema userSchema = this.authenticationService.getSignedUser(token.substring(SecurityInterceptor.AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME.length()).trim());
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(userSchema).build();
}
```

Comment: Edit: I moved that engine code from my library to the package where I will use and I registered the interceptor using a class that extends Application (JAX-RS) and the engine was triggered. But when I register the engine from library I got an error about @Inject. Also, I tried to register the JWTService  but this don't work.